# Deleting duplicated name form struct array in c

Tags: arrays, c, struct, typedef

i want to make the following thing: It should be possible to remove an animal with a specified name. If more animals with the same name exist, it should remove all the animal with the same name

my code in main.c:

```
            case 3: //Remove Animal 
                printf ("remove Animal\n");
                char animalName[MaxNameLength];
                printf("Animal name to delete: \n");
                scanf("%s", animalName);

                deleteAnimalByName(animalName, &nrOfAnimals, animals);
                 printf("Animal has been removed");
                break;
```

And my code in administration.c:

```
void deleteAnimalByName(char *animalName, int *nrOfAnimals, ANIMAL *animalArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < *nrOfAnimals; i ++)
   {
       if(strcmp((animalArray + i)->Name, animalName) == 0)
       {
           for(int j = i; j < *nrOfAnimals - 1; j++)
           {
               (animalArray + j)->Age = (animalArray + j + i)->Age;
               strcpy((animalArray + j)->Name, (animalArray + j + i)->Name);
               (animalArray + j)->Species = (animalArray + j + i)->Species;
           }
           *nrOfAnimals = *nrOfAnimals -1;
       }
   }

}
```

the outcome:
only one animal with the duplicated name get's deleted.. can someone help me with this problem? been stuck on this for quite some time.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: So should i add my whole code?

Comment: Please read the link. But no, not the whole code. Reduce your code to the minimum needed to repro the problem. For example, if there is code that asks for input that can be removed and replaced with static data. Remove any other code that isn't absolutely needed.

Comment: I think you are skipping checking of an element when you delete an item. Example: array = [a, b, c, c ,d]; You delete c, i = 2; and then you increment it to 3, but you just assigned the second "c" to the index 2. So it is skipped. Solution: don't increment i when you delete an  item.

Comment: do you mean in the for loop? because i tried deleting the i++ but that doesn't work

Comment: No, I meant like try adding i--; right after  *nrOfAnimals = *nrOfAnimals -1;

Answer (score 0):

Problem occures when you have 2 consecutive structs to dele inside the array:

```
array = ["dog", "cow", "cow", "fish"], toDelete="cow"
```

Algorithm printout:

```
i:0; array = ["dog", "cow", "cow", "fish"]
i:1; array = ["dog", "cow", "cow", "fish"]
    match is found
    you delete "cow" at index 1
    new array = ["dog", "cow", "fish"]
i:2; array = ["dog", "cow", "fish"]
    notice here the second "cow" was skipped because the i was incremented
```

**SOLUTION**:
When you delete an element from the array, reduce i by 1, to recheck the new element at that index.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your code:

1. Your current copy code is essentially moving the indices `animals[i + i]...animals[i + *nrOfAnimals - 1]` to `animals[i]...animals[i + *nrOfAnimals - 1]`. The destination part is fine, but the source part is pretty clearly erroneous; instead of `(animalArray + i + j)`, what you want is `(animalArray + j + 1)`, since you want to replace each item with the one immediately following it; `i + j` will be some larger index that might even be outside the bounds of the array!
2. Like @sadsad said in comments, when you move the segment of the array down in memory, you're not re-checking the element. One way around this is to replace the `if` with a `while`: as long as the element at index `i` is equal to `animalName`, it will delete that element, move down the rest of the array, and then loop back to check the newly-moved element again.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, this is the code after fixing it:

```
void deleteAnimalByName(char *animalName, int *nrOfAnimals, ANIMAL *animalArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < *nrOfAnimals; )
   {
       if(strcmp((animalArray + i)->Name, animalName) == 0)
       {
           for(int j = i; j < *nrOfAnimals - 1; j++)
           {
               (animalArray + j)->Age = (animalArray + j + i)->Age;
               strcpy((animalArray + j)->Name, (animalArray + j + 1)->Name);
               (animalArray + j)->Species = (animalArray + j + 1)->Species;
           }
           *nrOfAnimals = *nrOfAnimals -1;
       }
       else
       {
           i++;
       }
   }
}
```

the i++ was the problem.

Comment: You still have a `(animalArray + j + i)->Age` in there, just fyi